# Where can I find an ATM simulation software to investigate traffic flow capacities?

Tags: air-traffic-control, software, atc-simulator

Does anyone know what software is suitable to investigate air traffic flow capacities in various FIR's / routes. I need to see the effect of temporary reserved ares due to military activities, weather, changes of routing due to LOAs. Taking into account meteorological data would be advantage but it is not necessary.

It would be great if it will be possible to emphesize (colours, histogram, ...). usage of FIR areas.

What kind of software tools are used by EUROCONTROL or ATM consultancy firms providing this service. What standard tools commercially available (or for free)?

Comment: What do you want to investigate by simulation? If you want to investigate noise impact you use a different simulator than when you investigate throughput or conflict probability. Do you need to distinguish between aircraft types? Aircraft load factors? Airline operating procedures. Is wind a factor to take into acount? Thunderstorms? Air traffic control flow restrictions? Please clarify.

Comment: I need to investigate capacity usage in a different FIR areas/routes. How it will afect temporary reserved ares due to military activities, weather, changing current route due to LOAs. Meteorological data would be advantage but it is not necessary.It would be great if there will be possible to emphesize (colours, histogram, ...). usage of FIR ares.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about selecting software packages. Currently there are 1836 questions about Mathematica usage at [maths.se](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=mathematica+is%3Aquestion) so you might consider composing a question for that Q&A site.

Comment: Well this is special aviation software. It is difficult to use some general mathematical SW. Ok, I redefine to my question - which SW use EUROCONTROL or local bureaus experts for this simulation?

Comment: It might help to write in the Q in what ways [Simulink, ComDATSS etc](https://www.google.com/search?q=air+traffic+simulation+mathematica+OR+matlab) are not appropriate. (n.b. to redefine your question it is best to use the "edit" link under the question text)

Comment: On hold because my question is unclear? I think my question is clear enough and I sad exactly what I am asking for... Anyway, I have already found answer for my problem. ACES and FACET from NASA Aviation System Division solve my problem. It should handle all statistical data, it has statistical output as well and it could also handle meteorological data. Currently this SW use FAA and some airline companies to modelate ATM concepts (http://www.aviationsystemsdivision.arc.nasa.gov/).

Comment: Suggestion: If you don't think your question or answer will be of any help to other people, you could just delete the question. I think it would be better if you would add your answer (from your comment) below, elaborating a little, then accept it in a day or so.

Comment: RedGrittyBrick: I wanted to answer my question but it was on hold and I couldn't add it. One suggestion for you: you should post only related comments/answers. If you don't have enough information or you don't know answer you should postpone commenting. It is not related to math SW (trust me - I really made research about this problem) and if you don't think so, write answer with example. Otherwise, you are doing confusion.

Comment: "which SW use EUROCONTROL [use] for this simulation?" They have teams of developers to make these softwares for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have already found answer for my problem. ACES and FACET from NASA Aviation System Division solve my problem. It should handle all statistical data, it has statistical output as well and it could also handle meteorological data. Currently this SW use FAA and some airline companies to modelate ATM concepts (aviationsystemsdivision.arc.nasa.gov).
Thanks for all your help!